# Probability of coin toss

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability that a particular coin will land heads-up is $p$. In terms of $p$, calculate the
number of times the coin must be tossed in order to ensure that the probability of at least one heads is
greater than or equal to $0.8$.

Edit: I know the answer is $3$ due to the notion that every the probability that $N$ flips in a row are heads is $(0.5)^N$. So computing this for different values of $N$ is then

$$N=1 \implies 0.5$$
$$N=2 \implies 0.25$$
$$N=3 \implies 0.125$$

Therefore flipping the coin $3$ times will give me $(100−12.5)=87.5\%$ confidence that a heads will appear at least once

Having trouble putting that information in terms of $p$

Comment: please include what you have tried in the question.

Comment: Whether you get at least one head in $N$ tosses has very little to do with whether you get $N$ heads in a row. But it has everything to do with whether you get $N$ _tails_ in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we need $n$ trials.

We want $$1-P(\text{no head}) \geq 0.8$$

$$1-(1-p)^n \geq 0.8$$

Can you solve for $n$ in terms of $p$?

Comment: thank you so much! I got n ≥ 2.32 which is exactly 80% confidence

Comment: @Statsguy Does that mean that you had the value of p with you?

Comment: @learning p is the probability that the coin will land on heads so since the problem didn't state the coin was unfair, it is safe to assume that p is 0.5 or 1/2 as that is the odds that a fair coin will land on heads

Comment: @Statsguy I'm not sure if it's "safe" to assume that, but I guess it's fine just to see if it makes sense.

Comment: I interpret the question as that the coin could be unfair as the probability that it lands on head is $p$ which need not be equal to $0.5$. We can express $n$ in terms of $p$ rather than assuming that $p=0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability $p $ that there is at least one head is $1-(\frac 12)^N $ where $N $ is the number of tosses...

For this probability to be at least  $0.8$, we have  $$1-(\frac 12)^N\ge 0.8$$

Solving,  we get  $$0.2\ge(\frac 12)^N \\ \ln(0.2)\ge N\ln(0.5)\\N\ge\frac {\ln(0.2)}{\ln(0.5)} $$.
So $N\ge 3$, since  $N $ is a whole number. ..